# Angular2 Base64 sanitizing unsafe URL value

Tags: angular

Response from my server looks like following:

```
[{"coreGoalId":1,"title":"Core goal 1","infrastructure":"Sample Infrastructure","audience":"People","subGoals":null,"benefits":[{"benefitId":1,"what":"string","coreGoalId":1}],"effects":null,"steps":null,"images":[{"imagelId":1,"base64":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcU\nFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgo\nKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wgARCAIWAe4DASIA\nAhEBAxEB/8QAHAABAAIDAQEB"}]}]
```

I am trying to display the base64 image returned in it.

In my component:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.homeService.getGoals()
    .subscribe(
        goals => this.coreGoals = goals,
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

and then in template:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let goal of coreGoals">
        {{goal.title}}
        <img [src]="'data:image/jpg;base64,'+goal.images[0].base64 | safeHtml" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where safeHtml is a Pipe I created like following:

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtml {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

This gives me `Required a safe URL, got a HTML` error. What is going wrong here? If I remove the pipe from `<img />` then it says unsafe url.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You would need

```
bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(html);
```

instead of

```
bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was my mistake.

Comment: I also recommend you enable `pure:true` for you pipe

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. Our application 'X' used to store locally uploaded images by converting them to base64 before saving it to the database(We used to pop the intial data i.e **data:image/jpg;base64**). While recovering it to display, I had the same issue. I used to concat the popped data to the recovered base64 string. It used to throw the above error. So, we decided to store the entire converted string without popping it and now its working fine. See, if it helps!