# SecurityError: The operation is insecure with base64 Angular 2

Tags: angular, security, sanitize

I am getting error `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` while displaying image using `Base64`. I already applied `Sanitize` as below then also I am getting the error.

```
constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    transform(v: string) {
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(v);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Base64 sanitizing unsafe URL value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141534/angular2-base64-sanitizing-unsafe-url-value)

Comment: Did you get Any solution?

Comment: @PratikButani this is very old so I don't remember. Will check and revert you back.