# Ionic 3- display base64 image, sanitizing unsafe url value safevalue must use [property]=binding

Tags: angular, image, ionic-framework, base64, ionic3

I want to display base64 image for profile picture.
The image is stored in database as binary data and I converted this binary data into base64 using btoa(). now I want to bind this base64 image to img src 
I tried many ways but it's not working, please help
here is my code

**profile.ts code:**

```
profilePicture(binImage)
{
    if(binImage != null)
    {
        var imageData = btoa(binImage);
        //console.log("Base64 Image: ",imageData);
        this.displayImage = imageData;
    }
}
```

**profile.html code:**

```
<div class="profile-picture big-profile-picture" *ngIf="displayImage">
    <img src="data:Image/*;base64,{{displayImage}}">
</div>
```

[image: Check this image, it't not displaying the picture]

It is showing an error "sanitizing unsafe url value safevalue must use [property]=binding"

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: Yes. error: "sanitizing unsafe URL value"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141534/angular2-base64-sanitizing-unsafe-url-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Base64 sanitizing unsafe URL value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141534/angular2-base64-sanitizing-unsafe-url-value)

Answer (score 7):

Add a sanitizer and sanitize the url before using it in template

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...
constructor( private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, .... ) {}
...

profilePicture(binImage)
{
    if(binImage != null)
    {
        var imageData = btoa(binImage);
        //console.log("Base64 Image: ",imageData);
        this.displayImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("data:Image/*;base64,"+imageData);
    }
}
```

in your template just:

```
<div class="profile-picture big-profile-picture" *ngIf="displayImage">
    <img src="{{displayImage}}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add browser sanitizer and sanitize the url and rather then using **src="{{your_variable}}"** use **[src]="your_variable"**. For example:

```js
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-modal',
  templateUrl: './image-modal.page.html'],
})
export class ImageModalPage {
  user_image: SafeResourceUrl;
  constructor( private sanitizer: DomSanitizer ) { }
  
  loadImage(){
    this.user_image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(/* your base64 string in here*');
  }
}
```

```html
<img [src]="user_image" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to store the data twice, you can put the metadata string right in the html. This worked better for my scenario

```
<div class="profile-picture big-profile-picture">
    <img src="{{'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData}}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your typescript file, in CameraOptions  you can replace `FILE_URI` by `DATA_URL` like this `destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a public address for the URL, in case you have a server where they are saved, you must put the public address of your server and the password where the image is saved.